# Ansible/AWX/Tower ERROR! Neither the collection requirement entry key 'name', nor 'source' point to a concrete resolvable collection artifact

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-awx

I am trying to run a basic playbook using AWX but the playbook is always failing in the
`fetch galaxy collections from collections/requirements.(yml/yaml)`  task in the requirements.yml file. The error that I am getting is

> ERROR! Neither the collection requirement entry key 'name', nor 'source' point to a concrete resolvable collection artifact. Also 'name' is not an FQCN. A valid collection name must be in the format .. Please make sure that the namespace and the collection name  contain characters from [a-zA-Z0-9_] only.
>
> Tip: Make sure you are pointing to the right subdirectory — /var/lib/awx/projects/.__awx_cache/_8__testproject/stage/tmp/ansible-local-640q06qxv5r/tmpn_dk6jym/pylibsshmg6_wq45 looks like a directory but it is neither a collection, nor a namespace dir.

Version information:

```
ansible [core 2.13.1]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/Users/garandre/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/garandre/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.4 (v3.10.4:9d38120e33, Mar 23 2022, 17:29:05) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = False
```

My requiremnets.yml file looks like this:

```yaml
--- 
collections:
   - name: https://git@github.com/ansible/pylibssh.git
     type: git
     version: '0.4.0'
 
   - name: https://git@github.com/ansible-collections/cisco.iosxr
     type: git
     version: '3.2.0'
```

Most of the things that I have tried have been based on the documentation here:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/user_guide.html#installing-a-collection-from-a-git-repository.

Any help is appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: You have a `git` usernames in your https uri to github (probably pasted from an ssh uri). The first repo (pylibssh) does not point to an ansible collection.

Comment: I am confused on what you mean by "You have a git usernames in your https uri to github (probably pasted from an ssh uri)" Is there a way to install pylibssh from the requirements file?

Comment: `https://git@github.com/ansible/pylibssh.git` => `https://github.com/ansible/pylibssh.git`

Comment: And no, you cannot install something that is not a role or a collection from a requirement file dedicated to install roles or collections.